# jQuery - increment resize div on button click

Tags: jquery

I want to incrementally increase the size of the `.img` elements where there are three sizes (original, big, and max). The current code is supposed to get the size of the `.img` and then increment the value until the max is reached then restart back at the original height.

How do I change the code to increment three times(original, big, and max)?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function incSize(currentSize, incr, min, max) {
    fSize = ((parseFloat(currentSize) + incr) % max) + min;
    return fSize + "px";
  }
  var $this = $(this);
  $("button").click(function () {
    newFontSize = incSize($(".img").css("height"), 24, 46, 94);
    $(".img").css({
      height: newFontSize,
      width: newFontSize
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.img {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  border: 3px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Resize Image</button>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a more elegant way, but this works with `Math.max` and `Math.min`, and storing the original size beforehand.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function incSize(currentSize, incr, min, max) {
    if (parseFloat(currentSize) === max) return originalWidth;
    fSize =  Math.max(Math.min(parseFloat(currentSize) + incr, max), min);
    return fSize + "px";
  }
  var $this = $(this);
  var originalWidth = $(".img").css("width");
  $("button").click(function () {
    newFontSize = incSize($(".img").css("height"), 24, 46, 94);
    $(".img").css({
      height: newFontSize,
      width: newFontSize
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.img {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  border: 3px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Resize Image</button>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```